# Install "PMR" R package from Github

Tags: r, github, installation

I'm trying to install one R package with MacOSX with the command:

```
install_github("yuanzhongshang/PMR")
```

But there is an error:

```
Downloading GitHub repo yuanzhongshang/PMR@HEAD
✓  checking for file 
─  preparing ‘PMR’:
✓  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ...
─  cleaning src
─  installing the package to process help pages
         -----------------------------------
─  installing *source* package ‘PMR’ ...
   ** using staged installation
   ** libs
   clang++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/Rcpp/include" -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/RcppArmadillo/include" -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include -fopenmp  -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -Wall -pedantic -fdiagnostics-color=always -c EstimateVC_1.cpp -o EstimateVC_1.o
   clang: error: unsupported option '-fopenmp'
   make: *** [EstimateVC_1.o] Error 1
   ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘PMR’
─  removing
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: It looks like the package might not have been tested on a mac so the default mac tools won't work. See this guide to setting your system set up correctly to compile R packages from source: https://thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/cpp/r-compiler-tools-for-rcpp-on-macos/

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Sorry, I tried to follow that but the error does not go away. Also I have tried to install different versions of clang and gfortran but PMR doesn't work either.